# Full-text search runs slow on single rare word but runs fast when same word repeated?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with a GIN index similar to:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING GIN (to_tsvector('english', lower(
    (jsondoc->>'StreetAddress') 
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Neighborhood')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Area')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'CrossStreet')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Community')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Complex') )))
where source = 'x';
```

My table has 2.5M rows.

Suppose I want to query for the word `banana`, which is not a very common word in this dataset. In fact, it appears exactly 8 times.

Now here's the weird part.

This query takes a repeatable **3 full seconds** to execute:

```
select * from my_table where
(source='x' AND plainto_tsquery('english', 'banana') @@ to_tsvector('english', lower(
    (jsondoc->>'StreetAddress') 
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Neighborhood')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Area')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'CrossStreet')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Community')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Complex') )) AND (jsondoc->>'L_AskingPrice')::real>=250000 AND ((jsondoc->>'L_AskingPrice')::real<=2500000 OR (jsondoc->>'L_asking_price_low')::real<=2500000) AND jsondoc->>
'L_Status' IN ('ACTIVE','BACK ON MARKET') AND iscurrent='true')
```

while this executes reliably in just under **50 milliseconds**:

```
select * from my_table where
(source='x' AND plainto_tsquery('english', 'banana banana') @@ to_tsvector('english', lower(
    (jsondoc->>'StreetAddress') 
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Neighborhood')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Area')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'CrossStreet')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Community')
    || ' ' || (jsondoc->>'Complex') )) AND (jsondoc->>'L_AskingPrice')::real>=250000 AND ((jsondoc->>'L_AskingPrice')::real<=2500000 OR (jsondoc->>'L_asking_price_low')::real<=2500000) AND jsondoc->>
'L_Status' IN ('ACTIVE','BACK ON MARKET') AND iscurrent='true')
```

Can you spot the difference?

Yes: the word banana is repeated in the second query. Now, this is just an example. Through additional testing, I found that essentially **any single word** takes a long time (~3 seconds), while any double-word search (including, 2 different words) runs fast (~50ms).

PostgreSQL version is the latest (v11).

What could cause this?

**Query Plans**

Slow (one word)
[image: Slow]

Fast (one word repeated twice)
[image: Fast]

Comment: Difficult to say since you've kept the EXPLAIN ANALYSE output hidden from everyone.

Comment: @RichardHuxton see updates

Comment: Excellent question. But plaease provide data (incl. query plans) as *text*, never as image. The lines are truncated, too.

Comment: How? I’m using pgAdmin, there is no option to copy as text.

Comment: You can just select and copy the output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT...` in pgAdmin3, pgAdmin4 or psql (or any other client).

Comment: Seriously there is no option to copy the output from the text output window. Sorry I'm a longtime mysql user and find pgsql a little disorienting, perhaps this option is staring in my face and I can't see it.

Comment: That seems unlikely, although I don't have pgadmin in front of me to check. Your long-running query seems to be using a different query though - one against "asking price"? It's difficult to say more because you haven't bothered to tell anyone about your indexes or why you have hidden all this structured data in a json blob.

Comment: They are the exact same query, except for the ts_query piece which is causing the problem. The last part of your comment, "why you have hidden all this structured data in a json blob" is really unnecessary.

Comment: To answer this `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements are necessary, as well as text mode `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. Use `psql` to generate the latter.